# Outputting variables? (bash)

Tags: bash

I'm trying to put a variable into a line that gets put into a file.

The code looks like this:

```
echo "cd ~/Desktop/BukkitServer/" >> start.command
echo "java -Xms$ramM -Xmx$ramM -jar CraftBukkit.jar" >> start.command
chmod +x start.command
```

see how i put $ram in the second line? it ends up as

```
java -XmsM -XmxM -jar CraftBukkit.jar
```

how do i get it to put whatever $ram is in its proper place?

thanks :)

EDIT:

`echo 'java -Xms{$ram}M -Xmx{$ram}M -jar craftbukkit.jar' >> start.command`

produces `java -Xms{$ram}M -Xmx{$ram}M -jar craftbukkit.jar`

`echo "java -Xms{$ram}M -Xmx{$ram}M -jar craftbukkit.jar" >> start.command`

produces `java -Xms{120}M -Xmx{120}M -jar craftbukkit.jar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` is used to mark a variable. With your command you are telling echo to put `java -Xms` followed by the content of the `$ramM` variable in the file.

You have to define a value for the variable

```
ram=128
echo "java -Xms${ram}M"
```

will produce

```
java -Xms128M
```

Note that you will have to use brackets `{}` to delimit the variable name otherwise the shell will not know where your variable finishes.

If you want to put a literal `$` you will have to use single quotes (the shell will not interpret the content of the string).

```
echo 'java -Xms$ramM'
```

produces

```
java -Xms$ramM
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. I had already defined $ram but did not know about the { }. The only problem is now there are brackets around the number. as in:

`java -Xms{200}M -Xmx{200}M -jar craftbukkit.jar`

Comment: Where did you put the {}? Please edit your question with the new version (add it at end and leave the original one otherwise it will be difficult to follow"

Comment: AHHHHH i just realised i put the $ in the brackets. Thanks xD

Answer (score 0):

change your second line to :

`echo 'java -Xms'$ram'M -Xmx'$ram'M -jar CraftBukkit.jar' >> start.command`

Comment: This will produce exactly the same output the OP is already getting (`java -XmsM -XmxM -jar CraftBukkit.jar`)

Comment: @matteo NO!! output will be fine. Though this is not the elegant way of doing things as yours. In this case, the whole expression has been divided into 4 substrings and final output is the concatenation of the 4 substrings.